# Setting a password for a model(non User) in django for simple authentication

Tags: python, django

For my website, i am not planning to make it compulsory for the users to sign up. Instead, they can create a post and set a password for it in order to manage it. I can use the 'set_password' method django provides for the User model:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    import random
    algo = 'sha1'
    salt = get_hexdigest(algo, str(random.random()), str(random.random()))[:5]
    hsh = get_hexdigest(algo, salt, raw_password)
    self.password = '%s$%s$%s' % (algo, salt, hsh)
```

so that sorts out the storing password part. But this will hash the password (which is good) but now i am stuck on how to authenticate this?? So when someone wants to edit the instance of the model they have created, they first need to be authenticated. How do i go about doing that?

Thank you

Comment: You can use Django's `check_password` and thus copy this in your model as well. This will inspect the set password, and run the same hasher with the same salt and the same number of iterations, and see if the hashes match.

Comment: Salt should not be random, otherwise you will have such situation when you can not recreate same hash.

Comment: See https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L31-L62

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew: actually you can: the password field stores the salt, so in order to verify it, it will first analyze the hashed password, and then use the same algo and salt to check if the same hash can be retrieved.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can the password be stored in a CharField? It doesn't feel right

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar Sure you can. You can store it as md5 hash, then simply match hashes.

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew: please don't. md5 is considered "cryptographically broken": https://www.section.io/engineering-education/what-is-md5/ The idea of working with a hash that is saved together with the password is exactly to prevent the system against *rainbow table* attacks.

Comment: There are plenty other methods of string encryption, and we are not talking about what encryotion is better, we just want to help @ApoorvaShridhar to match password after encryption (any encryption)

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew: well the entire point of Django's hashing is to make the algorithm, salt, and number of iterations parameters, and thus "increase the search space enourmously". MD5 does not do that: it is possible for a given hash to generate a password that will match the hash in an effective manner (not taking years). Therefore MD5 is considered broken. It is also not necessary to pick a hasher: Django made utility functions for that that work with a random salt, and the `SECRET_KEY` of the Django app, thus render rainbow table attacks ineffective (as far as we know)